# Training anomaly detection on text string

Tags: machine-learning, python, pandas, k-nn

I have text string stored in a column, resulting after pre-processing of web traffic data. Now I want to apply anomaly detection on it and for that purpose I applied `countvectorizer` and `tf-idf_vectorizer`

**Data:**

- 0,   Mozilla Windows U Windows NT enUS AppleWebKit...
- 1,   Mozilla Windows NT rv Gecko Firefox
- 2,   Mozilla iPod U CPU iPhone OS like Mac OS X en...
- 3,   Mozilla Windows NT rv Gecko Firefox
- 4,   Mozilla compatible MSIE Windows NT NET CLR ...

Now tf-idf vectorized data looks as below, which is a 8000x1500 data:

[image]

Suggestion on how can I apply anomaly detection models on it.

Any Idea on how to apply following techniques will be highly appreciated.